# How to backup a rooted Samsung into a csc file

Tags: samsung, rooting, backup, data-transfer, systemless-root

Essentially, I have a Samsung Tab A7 that I rooted with Magisk, and it got damaged due to me dropping it, however, I have warranty and they will fix it for me. I was wondering if there is a way to save all the data into a single file, the csc one used when flashing the firmware, so that I can flash it to the new device after unlocking the bootloader and easily keep all data and root, without having to go through the hassle of rooting reinstalling and restoring data.

Also, I do not have a custom ROM, only magisk.

Comment: Since ~ Android 8 all user data is encrypted bound to the device. Thus creating backups on partition level is useless as the encryption is bound to the hardware. If your device is rooted creating an unencrypted data backup should be possible. But restoring data without root is impossible. Also apps that use AndroidKeystore are also bound to the hardware and can not be backup.

Comment: Ah, ok then. What would be an easy way to backup my apps data? because FlashFire apparently doesn't work on newer version of Magisk, and TitaniumBackup seems to not work as well, so what could I use to easily transfer my app data, installed apks, and other data?

Comment: Sorry I don't need backup on rooted devices so I can not answer you this, I only know what does not work.